# Selecionar no map/img

Tags: javascript, css

Após eu ter recortado essa imagem em estados, como eu poderia junta-las?

[image: Imagem]

Comment: O que você pretende? Você encontra isso pronto em SVG

Comment: Pretendo junta-las e relacionar com um link, ou seja.. até mesmo adicionar um funções javascript/css pra poder subir a imagem e na sequência exibir uma caixa de texto ou similar.

Comment: Juntar como amigo? Vc criou 26 imagens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta não está clara o suficiente, mas respondendo ao seu comentário

> Pretendo junta-las e relacionar com um link, ou seja.. até mesmo
>   adicionar um funções javascript/css pra poder subir a imagem e na
>   sequência exibir uma caixa de texto ou similar.

Se quiser ter mais liberdade, você vai precisar de um mapa no formato SVG para poder interagir com javascript e aplicar CSS a ele.

Para manipular o svg com uma maior facilidade, você pode usar a biblioteca D3. Segue abaixo links úteis e um pequeno exemplo de como pintar o mapa com css e javascript.

**Mapa do Brasil em SVG**

https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=brazil

**D3 Library**

https://d3js.org/

**Exemplo funcional**

https://codepen.io/malloni/pen/RxYygb

### Código

**HTML**

```
<div id="map">
    <!-- svg goes here -->
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
d3.select('#map>svg')
  .selectAll('path')
  .classed('land',true)
  .on('click', () => window.open('http://www.google.com.br/search?q=' + d3.event.target.id))
```

**CSS**

```
.land {
  fill: #33aa33;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.land:nth-child(2n) {
  fill: #ff3333;
}

.land:hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```